# iOS - a nice login window open source project?

Tags: iphone, ipad, open-source, authentication, dialog

I am just wondering whether there is a good login window open source that I can use?

Too many things need authentication, I just wish there would be an open source which give the developers a standard nice login window to easily use.

thanks

Comment: Use a tableview you can make nice login views with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QuickDialog](https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog) is a good choice not only for login screen but for any form screeen.